# Black blocks on Google map API v3

Tags: javascript, css, html, google-maps, google-chrome

I have problems with embedded Google map. I'm using API v3, and for some reason black blocks are rendered behind map controls and marker.

Here's the screenshot:

[image: Black boxes on google map]

I only have HTML5 doctors reset stylesheet, and some very simple custom styling for layout and typography. when I refresh page whole map blinks for a moment and then black blocks are rendered.

Here's codepen, but map is not displayed there for some reason. I have marked it with: [GOOGLE MAP] so it's easier to find.
http://codepen.io/Jinx/pen/bcrpn

**[UPDATE]**

I have created new html without any content except map `div` element and all scripts and css files from original html are included and map works properly.

This confuses me because it would appear that this bug is due to HTML surrounding the map?

**[UPDATE2]**

I got map to render on code pen but it has no controls and no marker. Still same result on local version.

**Could it be because I'm working locally?**

**[UPDATE3]**

I just checked in Firefox, Internet Explorer 9, Opera and Safari and map is rendered perfectly. This seems like **Chrome bug**.

Also, I have noticed that chrome is offsetting all element boxes out of browser window visible area. Here's a screenshot.

Inspectors in other browsers show boxes normally.

[image]

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: Please include relevant code.

Comment: I really don't understand upvotes sometimes, this question has no code, and very little relevant information, basically "why is this black box here?" How is that a good question?

Comment: @watson I was writing in a hurry, and forgot to put codepen link

Comment: You are supposed to put the relevant code in the question, in case codepen doesn't exist in a year, so your question will still be relevant to others. Also you should remove everything from your example except what is relevant... that is to say, nothing but the map and the code that creates the map.

Comment: @watson, code is a little to big for that, and I can't just paste `<div id="map"></div>`

Comment: You'd have thought Google Maps API would run perfectly on chrome and not so well on the others, not the other way round!

Answer (score 2):

It would seem this was indeed **Chrome bug**. I have just made copy of my project folder, and opened index.html from there and everything is fine.

I guess this was some *cache* problem/bug.

Comment: It is indeed a cache bug. I had the same problem. When I opened the same webpage in "incognito mode", the blocks disappeared

Answer (score -1):

It is black because you have a CSS style setting it to black with a color or image that is being inherited. Check your CSS for `#000000` as a background color or `url()` for an image.

Comment: I'm quite sure that isn't the case.